# DOM - control screen updates programmatically

Tags: javascript, dom, render

I have a complicated page that is built 99% dynamically via JavaScript. It has hundreds of event handlers attached to various fields and at some point I'm done with that incarnation of the page and want to refresh it leaving only the original 1% and adding the 99% again from scratch.

I'd like to ask the DOM to stop updating the screen when I remove a single element that is at the apex of the 99% of the page. That element ( a div ) has thousands of things hanging from it. Is it possible to issue some call to stop all screen updates and then via another call to repaint the entire screen and continue on as normal?

On a similar note, I periodically need to add one or more columns to an existing massive table. I can't reasonably use a single fragment to do this, so that's out. I'd again like to ask the DOM to ignore changes till I tell it to repaint the screen. While my code is adding columns, I don't want any flicker or other visual clues that this is going on, and I don't want to put up some dummy page. I want what's already there to stay there till the whole thing can be replaced and only then ask the DOM to repaint the page. Is this possible ? If so, how?

Comment: Browsers don't do any rendering until all the JS returns and it goes back to the event loop. The exception is if you use explicit animation operations or transitions in CSS.

Comment: This almost sounds like the problems the creators of `react` thought about, before coming up with it. Have you checked out [`react`](https://reactjs.org/)?